# HTML and SELECT element odd behavior

Tags: html

I have a chunk of C the kicks out html 4.01 strict with very minimal CSS.  One of the elements on the page is a dirt simple "select" element which is inside an absolute positioned div thus :

```
<div style="
position: absolute;
left: 260px;
top: 440px;
width: 200px;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
border: none;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: normal;
text-align: left;
overflow: auto;
color: #000000; " >
<select tabindex=36 name="vnd_bmid" class="inp_uline" 
        id="vnd_bmid" title="Assigned Name" style="width: 160px"
        onFocus="this.style.background='#eeeeee';"
        onBlur="this.style.background='#e7caea';" >
  <option value="0" selected >&nbsp;not assigned&nbsp;</option>
  <option value="1000001">Some String</option>
  <option value="1000002">Some Other String</option>
  <option value="1000045">Yet Another</option>
  <option value="1234567">This is wide</option>
  <option value="1874124">This is even more wide</option>
  <option value="1987654">Not Wide</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Regardless what I seem to do I can not get the little drop down arrow on the right of the element to respond when I click on it. I have to position my mouse on the extreme left of the element, where the text begins, and then click on it to get a drop down with the options listed. I have tried to use "overflow" and that has no effect. Removed it entirely. No effect. Ensured that I had a CSS width parameter inside the "select" and that has no effect. I have tried both Firefox and Opera and I see the same weird behavior on both browsers.  The W3C Validator says I have perfect HTML 4.01 Strict and CSS is clean.

At great risk of asking the obvious, what could cause a select element to behave this way and how do I get that little drop down arrow to behave?

Also, I should add in the class style bits to be complete :

```
.inp_uline
    {
        font-family: Lucida Console,monospace;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 2px;
        background-color: transparent;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
        border-color: darkred;
        color: #000000;
    }
```

So there we have everything that describes the select element and while someone may be able to get it to look nice on some "fiddle" it does not work inside this page I have with fifty other input elements.  I must also point out there are other select elements that work as expected however this one does not.

Comment: While I am laughing pretty hard at the title, you may as well go ahead and change it, because somebody else will if you don't :-)

Comment: I have no clue what you are talking about... your fiddle works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/vLNLt/

Comment: Ah well.  Perhaps the issue is in the class="inp_uline" bits. Also while "fiddle" is a nice petrie dish I do have the exact bit on my html output where other select elements work, but not this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing the unreasonable and impossible. I moved the entire absolute position of the div to the right by 300 pixels.  The element ( another select drop down also ) that was already in that location I moved to the left by 300 pixels.  This essentially moved the position of the two drop down select elements on the page by swapping their graphical locations.  Suddenly both of them work as expected where previously only one of them did.

No clue why.

Comment: sorry to all the helpful folks but the only way I could get the required result was to move the DIV around. It makes no sense and seems to suggest there is a fault in the way the browser renders the page. However it is W3C HTML 4.01 strict compliant and CSS clean. Really annoying.